# Different starting values between series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I want to see if $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+n} $ is convergent I would use the comparison test. I would set up the inequality $\frac{1}{n^2+n}\leq \frac{1}{n^2} $. I could use the p-series test but in my book, the p-series test works with $n$ starting at 1. So would I be able to say that because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $ is convergent, $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+n} $ is convergent? Would the difference in starting values between the series make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist to have the first few terms, a trick is that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 3}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+n}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+n}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Anyway, by loosing finite terms of the summands does not affect the convergence.

Comment: So in other words your'e saying if an infinite sum is convergent and we add in more terms into that sum, the new infinite sum is still convergent correct?

Comment: Yes, but just finite terms.

Comment: does this principle work with divergent sums as well?

Comment: Yes, it works for divergence.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour for series is independent from the fixed starting value that is $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=n_1}^\infty a_n <\infty$ both converge or not converge.

Of course in case of convergence their value are different in general.

Usually the starting point is fixed in order to have $a_n$ well defined.